# Dynamically load images via URL string in Android

Tags: android

I have an image gallery and am just following the example that everybody uses that the guys at Android wrote and I get the images from the res/drawable folder as below.

```
Integer[] imageIDs = {
    R.drawable.pic1,
    R.drawable.pic2,
    R.drawable.pic3,
    R.drawable.pic4
};
```

Is there a way I can load images dynamically from the web as done in a webpage e.g..

```
<img src="Swipe/images/1.jpg" width="350" height="197" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put the following code inside a try-catch block:

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpUrlConnection)<your file url>.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

<bgImage> = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
<image view>.setImageBitmap(<bgImage>);
```

Comment: <your file url> should be in URI format, as in Uri.parse(string)

Answer (score 0):

I would HIGHLY recommend [DroidFu - WebImageView](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/) (blog walkthrough link; there's a source link there too) as an alternative to writing code to handle images downloaded from the web.

It is simple to implement, handles all the HTTP connection stuff, loading images in the background and displaying them when loaded, all kinds of good stuff. This is especially useful when you're loading multiple images from the web in a single activity.